# CMake unit structure with many tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

I would like to set up cmake to run on a project with unit testing. The project structure is as follows:

```
|---CMakeLists.txt
|---build
|---source
|   |---CMakeLists.txt
|   |---many .cpp and .h files
|---tests
|   |---CMakeLists.txt
|   |---many .cpp files
```

The source files in `tests` use Boost `unit_test.h` library.

My outer `CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

project(MyProject CXX)
add_subdirectory(source)
add_subdirectory(tests)
enable_testing()
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` in the `source` folder is:

```
file( GLOB LIB_SOURCES *.cpp )
file( GLOB LIB_HEADERS *.h )
add_library( MyProject_lib ${LIB_SOURCES} ${LIB_HEADERS} )
```

And the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `tests` folder is:

```
# require old policy to allow for source files containing the name "test"
cmake_policy(SET CMP0037 OLD)
# Locate Boost libraries: unit_test_framework, date_time and regex
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.59 REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework date_time regex)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source" ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB APP_SOURCES *.cpp)
foreach(testsourcefile ${APP_SOURCES})
    string(REPLACE ".cpp" "" testname ${testsourcefile})
    add_executable(${testname} ${testsourcefile})
    target_link_libraries(${testname} LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} MyProject_lib)
    add_custom_target(targetname)
    add_custom_command(TARGET targetname POST_BUILD COMMAND ${testname})
endforeach(testsourcefile ${APP_SOURCES})
```

If I comment the lines with `add_custom_target` and `add_custom_command`, the result of this configuration is that the library is correctly built and linked, but none of the tests is compiled.

If I do not comment the two lines with `add_custom_target` and `add_custom_command`, The error I get by running `cmake` is:

```
CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:25 (add_custom_target):
add_custom_target cannot create target "targetname" because another target
with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
created in source directory "/tests".  See
documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

Since I have a large number of tests, listing them one by one is not practical. I would like to have cmake to find all the .cpp files, as done for the library in the source folder, compile and run them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I use in my library:

```
FILE( GLOB log_testprograms *.cpp )

FOREACH( testsource ${log_testprograms} )
   GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT( filename ${testsource} NAME_WE )
   celma_add_celma_boost_testprogram( ${filename} )
ENDFOREACH()
```

`celma_add_celma_boost_testprogram` is a macro like this:

```
macro( celma_add_celma_boost_testprogram  filename )
   add_executable(        ${filename}  ${filename}.cpp )
   target_link_libraries( ${filename}  celma ${Boost_Test_Link_Libs} )
   add_test(              ${filename}  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${filename} )
endmacro( celma_add_celma_boost_testprogram )
```

Celma is the name of my library, the variable `Boost_Test_Link_Libs` contains the list of Boost libraries to link against, including the Boost.Test library.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solves the problem of compiling the source files in the `tests` folder, but how to run the executables after compiling and linking them?

Comment: When you use the `add_test` command, you can simple type `make test` afterwards to run all test programs.

Comment: If I type `make test`, I receive the warning `No tests were found!!!`. If I add the following line to the macro:

    ```add_custom_command(TARGET ${filename} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${filename})```


Then it works, but I don't think this is the right way of using cmake for unit testing.

Comment: Those few lines I posted should be enough. Maybe you should move your `enable_testing` call before the `add_subdirectory` calls.